# gitlab server is not starting, getting below mentioned error

Tags: gitlab

Can anyone help me resolve the issue I am getting during GitLab configuration? The error message is below.

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1BcZE.png)

Comment: do you have redis installed?

Comment: Hi David, I thought  redis will be automatcally installed with gitlab packages.

Comment: I think it does actually yes. In your screenshot there is no error. it just seems to be waiting for redis to be available on the expected port? what happens after a while longer?

Comment: working fine now, David